# Am I right in doing such an edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, spam

Today I saw a post with abusive words.

I flagged the post, waited for 10 mins, and after that I did an edit.

I am right in doing such an edit?

> [image]

[Here is the link to the question. If a mod reads this, please delete the post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470854/twitter-oauth-invalid-expired-token/18436402#18436402)

Comment: In short: Editing like this makes it harder for moderators to see patterns of abuse and spam

Comment: I regret for the Duplicate post.

Comment: Wow, that guy even sucks when trolling...PHP does not allow hyphens in variable names, so that script would yield a syntax error. ... Why didn't you leave a comment calmly telling him that? Would have been better then that edit. Especially because this is not spam, it should be flagged as offensive and you should move on. ... Not to mention that the variable is called `$users_brain` but actually only holds the users name...